# Newsstand app update and download issues in background

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ipad, newsstand-kit

HHi everyone,

I am currently developing background downloading for Newsstand app.

The logic is like below,

1. receiving Push Notification
2. *(app will be launched in background)*
3. requesting lastest issues to server
4. downloading the issue

It was successful until 2. 
But the app doesn't work after requesting the newest issues.
After the app becomes foreground it continue working, though...

I noticed that if there is a logic which uses the timer then app doesn't work anymore in background.

`[self performSelector:@selector(methodName) withObject:nil afterDelay:1.0];`

You know, requesting something to server is basically asynchronous.

I have no idea with this situation.
Do you think I need to send all data of the new issue within Push Notification payload?

Any help would be appreciated! :)
Thank you very much!

Comment: You need to use NKAssetDownload class.